# c# Why not throw ArgumentNullException?

Tags: c#, exception

I was just reading [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173163.aspx) that I shouldn't throw `ArgumentNullException` from within my own source code. Why is this?

If I have a method that shouldn't be passed `null`, why not check the parameter and throw if it is indeed null?

```
public void DoStuff(List<Int32> list)   // Shouldn't be null.
{
   if(list == null)   // If input is null...
      throw new ArgumentNullException();

   ...
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where does it say you shouldn't throw ArgumentNullException? All I can see is: "Do not throw System.Exception, System.SystemException, System.NullReferenceException, or System.IndexOutOfRangeException intentionally from your own source code."

Comment: You may want to use System.Object.ReferenceEquals method to check for null.  That is because the "==" operator can be overloaded by a derived class.

Comment: @James: operators are defined static in a concrete class. They have no concept of beeing virtual. If a descendant class of List defines new operators, they aren't visible here.

Comment: No idea why this question has soo many downvotes. I think the voting system is missunderstood. Only downvote when the question is confusing or not well done. This question is pretty clear event when it starts with a wrong assumption.

Comment: @SoMoS - You said it yourself, the author makes the wrong assumption, thus the reason for my downvote.

Comment: @codymanix: maybe you're right; it's been awhile since I ran into this issue but I do distinctly remember at one point I had a situation where I got a NullReferenceException when comparing an object to null using "==".  I was using C++/CLI instead of C# at the time though, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Yep, my bad everyone. I did a search and skimmed too quickly. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That reference doesn't say any such thing (I can't find ArgumentNullException mentioned on that page).  It does say not to throw a NullReferenceException, which is a completely different exception and should indeed not be thrown from your own code (you have no reason to).

I throw ArgumentNullException from my own code all the time, and so does the .NET Framework when checking parameters.

Comment: Is there any purpose to throwing ArgumentNullException in any case where it won't cause one to avoid altering the state of a non-temporary object prior to the null argument itself triggering an exception?  If an exception is going to get thrown regardless, does it really matter where it happens?

Comment: The advantage of explicitly checking for null is that you're explicitly checking and enforcing the function contract: the caller may not pass null.  The generally expected exception to be thrown when this is the case is ArgumentNullException.  Allowing the NullReferenceException to be thrown because you didn't check is more along the lines of exposing an implementation detail.  (What if null isn't allowed, but the code doesn't crash anyway, and then a future maintainer adds code that would cause NullReferenceException to throw?  Or vice versa?  Best to explicitly enforce it so it's clear.)

Comment: I can somewhat understand that logic, but adding the explicit check would seem to clutter up the code and also slow down the main-line case.  If the contract of the method specifies that it will throw ArgumentNullException if given a null argument, it needs to make sure that's what happens (instead of NullReferenceException), but from a practical perspective I don't really see any advantage to such a contract versus one which specifies that it will cause either NullReferenceException or ArgumentNullException, without specifying which.

Comment: If we decide to follow the documentation, we must not throw NullReferenceException.  Therefore, the only way your function contract can allow a NullReferenceException is by exposing an implementation detail that causes that exception to be thrown.  (Besides, ArgumentNullException is the expected exception that most .NET programmers expect to see when passing a null argument.  Mixing both just gets confusing.)

Comment: Regarding clutter, you should take a look at the production-level code in Microsoft's own .NET Framework.  (Use Reflector to decompile, or just download the source direct from Microsoft).  I routinely see every parameter carefully verified.  Sometimes most of the function seems to consist of parameter verification - not "actual" work!

Comment: @supercat "but adding the explicit check would seem to clutter up the code and also slow down the main-line case."  Enforcing the method's contract is not clutter (and you can actually use Code Contracts, for example, to move the checks out of the main implementation).  As for your peformance concerns, I really don't care how fast your method is if it bombs the second it gets data it can't handle.

Comment: @Andy: Suppose method 1 and method 2 are identical except that method 1's contract says that passing in a null argument will throw `ArgumentNullException`, while method 2 says that passing a null argument will arbitrarily throw either `ArgumentNullException` or `NullReferenceException`.  For method 1 to uphold its contract, it must do the null check and throw `ArgumentNullException`, granted, but I don't see the use of the contractual guarantee that it won't throw `NullReferenceException` instead.  Calling a method that requires a non-null argument, and attempting to access a class member...

Comment: ...both indicate an assumption that a particular reference will not be null, and both aforementioned exceptions indicate that code made such an assumption and it did not hold.  To my mind, whether code hits an `ArgumentNullException` first or a `NullReferenceException` first should be considered a matter of chance.  To be sure, if one has a dictionary-ish collection that requires `Value` to be non-null, one should ensure that trying to store a null value will throw some kind of exception rather than corrupt the collection, but that doesn't imply a functional difference between ANE and NRE.

Comment: @JamesJohnston: There are some circumstances in which I've seen Framework methods let `NullReferenceException` escape.  I don't fault them for that--I simply regard `NullReferenceException` and `ArgumentNullException` as being semantically equivalent.  While I regard the Framework as certainly being both well-designed overall and useful, that does not mean I think every aspect of it is flawless.  Clearly there were some major design mistakes in .net 1.0, some of which have been corrected in later versions and some of which have been left alone for reasons of compatibility or consistency.

Comment: @JamesJohnston: I could see a usefulness for testing arguments and throwing `ArgumentNullException` if there were a decent means by which code which calls `foo(Bar)` could catch an `ArgumentNullException` which was thrown because `Bar` was null, from an `ArgumentNullException` which was called because `foo` called `boz`, which accidentally passed a null parameter to a nested call of `foo`, but the exception infrastructure doesn't provide a good mechanism for distinguishing deliberately-thrown exceptions from ones that unexpectedly bubble up the call stack.

Comment: @supercat The contract is not what may or may not be thrown; its a requirement placed on the caller that the caller must obey for the method to fullfil its responsiblity.  The difference is that one clearly indicates it's the callers fault (by calling the method will null), the latter the caller is left guessing (can the call take null, or is there a defect in the method).   I don't understand your matter of chance; as developers we expect computers to reliably behave the same way given the same inputs.

Comment: @supercat  Most of your argument doesn't make sense; there's no functional difference between ANY exception, its the semanics we associate with them that provide the value.  I don't think the fact that some NRE occur from the framework should auotmatically be intereperated as intended behavior; more likely they are oversights.

Comment: @Andy: If a method contract specifies that the caller must meet certain conditions, but does not explicitly say what should happen if the conditions are not met, a caller who does not satisfy the stated conditions is not entitled to expect any particular behavior.  One may argue that contracts should be written to require that methods throw an exception if their callers have not met their contract, but if they aren't, in the absence anything explicitly specifying otherwise, I would posit that failure of a caller to abide by its contract frees the method to do whatever is most convenient.

Comment: @Andy: As for exceptions, I would suggest that the main reason for having different exception types is to allow code to catch some exceptions but not others.  Under what cases, should code catch an ANE but not an NRE, or vice versa?  Are there any other circumstances when it should matter which was thrown?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22779/discussion-between-andy-and-supercat)

Comment: @supercat ArgumentNullException: as the name implies, it's the exception to raise whenever an argument is null that shouldn't be. It implies that the caller violated the function contract, which states that an ArgumentNullException would be thrown if the argument is null. Why on earth would you want to declare your contract to throw a NullReferenceException when an argument is null, when every other function does the opposite and throws ArgumentNullException?  (Note this is different from a contract stating that a null argument results in undefined behavior, in which case any exception is OK).

Comment: @supercat NullReferenceException:  this is supposed to only be raised by the .NET Runtime in response to an attempt to dereference a null reference.  This is the definition: "The exception that is thrown when there is an attempt to dereference a null object reference."  Effectively, this is the managed equivalent of dereferencing a NULL pointer in "old-school" native C/C++.  It is ALWAYS indicative of a severe bug and if you get one, you should thank your lucky stars that you are working in a language where you didn't enter the realm of undefined behavior, unlike C/C++.

Comment: @JamesJohnston: Constraining a function to *only* throw ANE forces it to either add code and cycles to the mainline case checking its argument, or else catch NRE and--if the argument was null--rethrow as ANE. Neither seems elegant. Specifying that it has Undefined Behavior will often force the caller to add code and cycles to the mainline to avoid completely Undefined Behavior propagating outward. A major difference between .net and "old-school" C is that a null reference is causes Undefined Behavior in C, but not in .net (so far as I know; is there any indication that .net could...

Comment: ...ever do anything in response to a null dereference other than throw an NRE?  If so, that would certainly be a basis for seeking to avoid them; if the early designers of .net weren't sure about whether NRE's would be reliably trapped, that would have been a compelling reason for avoid them at the time, but perhaps less compelling now.  To use a rough analogy, if one is using a language/framework where integer arrays are not guaranteed initialized to zero, manual initialization is important.  If auto-initialization is guaranteed, manual initialization is redundant.  I'll grant that...

Comment: ...in some cases the extra info supplied by an ANE (vs an NRE) may be helpful, so code to throw the former rather than the latter is not without value, but I would think that, especially for internal-use-only methods, there would be room for judgment on whether that value was worth the code-clutter and execution-time costs.

Comment: @JamesJohnston: I guess my thought is that if a method's purpose is to do something with a *reference* that must not be null (e.g. add it to a dictionary), it should throw ANE if the reference is null, but if it's supposed to do something with the *object* the reference refers to (e.g. `void StrikeTarget(IDamageable Target) { Target.TakeDamage(15, this); }` I'd expect that passing a null would likely cause an NRE, since the whole *purpose* of the function is to dereference `Target`.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you should. Event your own link has this example as the first one. If the method is public you should check always the parameter validity.

The link only talks about NullReferenceException and this only happens when you try to access a method of a null reference object. It's right to not throw NullReferenceExceptions as they are thrown only by the runtime.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong in throwing ArgumentNullException, it is a good practice.

the article is talking about System.Exception, System.SystemException, System.NullReferenceException, or System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible to use a default value for a null parameter, and as long as the default value is clearly documented, then it might be worth considering that option.

However, you should always validate any parameters in a public method. Don't trust other developers to know what they're doing. Any exceptions thrown as a result of an invalid argument should inherit from the `ArgumentException` class.

Answer (score 0):

Because if you throw a **NullReferenceException **, that means you anticipated that one of the objects would could have a null reference to itself.  It would be better to handle this issue with programming the logic into your code as opposed to relying on an exception to handle it.

Exceptions should not be used to change the flow of a program as part of ordinary execution. They should only be used to report and handle error conditions.

Comment: The question is about `ArgumentNullException`, not `NullReferenceException`.